# Pulling data out of an worksheet by country

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a huge amount of people in my excel sheet and I want to split them by country with excel coding, here is an example of my data:

```
Country | Name
UK      | Tom
Austria | Bobsky
UK      | Ralf
Germany | Badolf
Germany | Schwartz
UK      | Andy
```

**So would it be possible to just separate the people who are in the UK into s different part of my spreadsheet?**
I have already tried 
    `INDEX(B1:B6, MATCH("UK", A1:A6,0))` - this returns a repeated row if the match function returns no result
I have also tried many things with 
    `if(VLOOKUP(etc etc) = "UK".....`
and I have found this doesn't work either. I thought this would be something excel could do simply without having to filter + copy & paste or use VBA but this is not easy.

Comment: You can auto-filter the columns.  Then select the country you want and just copy those rows over.

Comment: Look toward [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable for a couple thousand rows of data. If your *'huge amount of people'* is much more than that, an advanced filter or pivot table is a more viable solution.

[image: INDEX SMALL ROW]

With *UK* in D3 use the following in E3.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9999, SMALL(INDEX(ROW($1:$9995)+($A$2:$A$9996<>D3)*1E+99, , ), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: This is the one, I cannot believe you have actually solved this, Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Without wasting time to draft a complex Excel formula:

### Option 1

Use a PivotTable where you use the Country column as a filter

### Option 2

Use a Microsoft Query `Data->From Other Sources->Microsoft Query` on each worksheet like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Country = 'UK' ORDER BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub processData()
'I have workout for only UK 
'this macro copies records of UK people from Sheet1 to Sheet2
lastrows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
count = 1
For x = 2 To lastrows
    If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1) = "UK") Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(count, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(count, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2)
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next x
MsgBox "Task finished"
End Sub
```